# How do I fix errors regarding the language markup of my webpage?

Tags: language, text

The language set or defined for my webpage is en-us. But unfortunately, the language detected for text on the page is sk. I have reset the language from setting to en-us on several times but it doesn't work. I have change my theme name but it's still not fixed. Please, kindly help me out.

Comment: Do you have `<head lang="en-US">` at the top of the page? If not, you can get your theme to generate this by putting `<?php language_attributes(); ?>` inside the tag - see one of the default WordPress themes' header.phps.

Comment: But if that's already there, and if you don't have any other language tags, then the problem is that Google or Bing are detecting that your text looks like Slovak. We can only guess why they think that sorry.

Comment: Are you including iframes or content from other sources? Is there any chance they're set to Slovak?